# What needs to be done to backup the IOTA wallet?

Tags: wallet

What needs to be done to backup the IOTA wallet?

Is it sufficient to keep the seed in a backup location (such as maybe [Password Safe](https://www.pwsafe.org/) or [KeePass](https://www.keepassx.org/downloads)), or is it also necessary to backup any file from the system where the wallet is installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current wallet is stateless, so when you log out it will not keep any data itself. So keeping the seed in a safe location (or two) is everything you need.

Comment: thank you mihi. So also if I need to reinstall my entire system I don't necessarily need to backup any files from the wallet?

Comment: Yes. Perhaps you want to back up the installer in case you reinstall your system more often :)